# How to specify max length string if I have a default already set?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Normally I can specify `.HasMaxLength(null)` and this will result in a string column of maximum length (`nvarchar(MAX)`).

I think in fact this is actually the default, and if you don't specify a length then you get `nvarchar(MAX)`.

However, it is possible to set a default using code like this:

```
DbModelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(config => config.HasMaxLength(50));
```

This will result in all string columns by default having `nvarchar(50)` (a max length of 50).

But then, this seems to prevent `.HasMaxLength(null)` from working, and I can no longer choose maximum length. I tried also saying `.HasMaxLength(null).HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")` and this worked for generating the right column at the database level, but then I found that EF is still throwing an exception when my length exceeds 50 characters.

Is there a way around this, or will I have to go through and manually set most string columns back to `.HasMaxLength(50)` and forget about having a default length that is different from `nvarchar(MAX)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the solution here is to use the `.IsMaxLength()` method.

`.IsMaxLength()` is I guess the default, and says "use the maximum length" (`nvarchar(MAX)`).

`.HasMaxLength(null)` does not say to use the maximum length, it says to use the default length, and the default default length is the maximum length (the result of calling `.IsMaxLength()` which is `nvarchar(MAX)`).